# Change style based on checkboxes w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to change the style of the entire row when a checkbox in that row is checked or unchecked.

```js
function myFunc() {
    if ($(".chkbx:checked").length) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","red");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","green");
    }
}

myFunc();

$(".chkbx").change(myFunc);
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" checked></td>
        <td>label 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" checked></td>
        <td>label 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" checked></td>
        <td>label 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I think I'm missing something here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.chkbx').change(function(){
    var $this  = $(this), 
        color = ($this.is(':checked')) ? 'red' : 'green';
    $this.closest('tr').css('background-color', color);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6dR8C/1/

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but typically you'll see variables starting with a $ being jQuery objects when using the jQuery framework. `$color` makes it seem as though the variable is reverencing jQuery, `color` would be a better choice in my opinion as its just a string.

Answer (score 1):

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGvuF/1/).

The issue is your `if` is checking all the elements matching `.chkbx:checked`. This is true if *any* of the check boxes are checked. You have to check just the one checkbox, `this`.

*Update*: With initialization of styles is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGvuF/2/).

Comment: You're right. I need to assign the style on page load too, and not just on click. +1 for jsfiddle

Comment: Imaginary -1 for forcing everybody to go to another website to see your solution. If JSFiddle ever goes away, this answer becomes useless.

Comment: @santa I've updated the jsFiddle.

Comment: @PHPBree As soon as stackexhange supports the features that jsFiddle does, I'll stop using jsFiddle.

Comment: Nothing is forever... But having an instant working prototype helps tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chkbx").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest("tr").css('background-color' ,'red');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest("tr").css('background-color' ,'green');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Some of the checkboxes can be checked on page load, and I need to apply the style on page load, before I click any checkboxes.

Comment: @Purmou `closest` will work fine.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Absolutely. In fact, I think I should get used to using closest a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution : http://jsfiddle.net/gDtLX/

Basically, your `if` statement was a bit off, as it would always be true if *any* of the checkboxes was checked. Then, on load, instead of manually calling the function with `myFunc()`, you can trigger the change event on every checkboxes using jQuery's `trigger()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CSS class then add/remove that class on whether the checkbox is checked or not

```
$(function(){
  $("input.chkbx").click(function(){
    if($(this).is("checked")) {
      $(this).parent("tr").addClass('checkedRow');
    } else {
      $(this).parent("tr").removeClass('checkedRow');
    }
  });
});
```

By using classes the color (or other styling) can easily be modified via stylesheets.

Comment: Yes, I'll change to class. I need to make sure the styles are applied on load to, not just on click. Thanks.

Comment: In your example script you're calling myFunc() on page load which will do that for you. :)

Comment: Yah, that was the idea... but something was not right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get it, you want to iterate through your checkboxes and make table row red if checkbox are red, and green otherwise. Also, you want to make this every time when any checkbox are changed.

You should use jQuery's "each" method to iterate through checkboxes. Like this:

```
function myFunc() {
  $('.chkbx').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this); 
      if ($this.is(':checked')) {
          $this.parents('tr').css("background-color","red");
      } else {
          $this.parents('tr').css("background-color","green");
      }
  });  
}

myFunc();

$(".chkbx").change(myFunc);
```

You can see working example with source code here: 
http://jsbin.com/awexak/edit#preview